# continuity of general function with blocked partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, with blocked partial derivatives at the neighborhood of $(0,0)$.
I'm trying to formulate that f is continuous at $(0,0)$, I think it's should be easy argue that by Lagrange's sentence, but the point is that it's not given that the partial derivatives are continuous or should I infer it ?

If anyone can explain, I'll appreciate.

Comment: By "blocked" you mean "bounded"? Or do you mean "continuous"? If the partial derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable, and this will imply continuity. What is "Lagrange's sentence"?

Comment: I meant Mean value theorem (of Lagrange's), and by blocked means bounded at the neighborhood of $$(0,0)$$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood of the origin tells you that the restriction of the function to any line parallel to the axes is continuous (near the origin). So, yes, you can apply the one-variable Mean Value Theorem by writing
$$f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \big[f(x,y)-f(x,0)\big] + \big[f(x,0)-f(0,0)\big].$$
For then we have (for some $\xi$ and $\eta$ in appropriate intervals)
$$f(x,y) - f(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi)y +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\eta,0)x.$$
If the partial derivatives are bounded near the origin, then the expression on the right-hand side approaches $0$ as $x,y\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation, one thing I think I misunderstood, how is the fact that the partial derivatives are bounded near the point (0,0) helps us to infer that the expression approaches to zero. Isn't it because we got 
$$A*x +B*y$$ 

and x,y goes to 0,0 ? 
or we can't say that.

Comment: when A,B are the values of partial derivatives

Comment: More specifically, if on our neighborhood of $(0,0)$ we have $$\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|, \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right| \le C,$$ then $|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| \le C(|x|+|y|)$, and the right-hand side goes to $0$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

Comment: You should accept answers once you are satisfied.